# Browser opens many times while Geb testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spring-boot, selenium-chromedriver, spock, geb

I wrote the following test for my simple Spring Boot Web application:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=[PDK])
@WebIntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext
class GebMainpageSpec extends GebSpec {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    def setup() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver/win32/chromedriver.exe");

        browser.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        browser.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";


    }

    def 'Static page present and works, check without pages'() {

        when:
            go ""

        then:
            assert title == "MyApp"

    }

    def 'Static page present and works, check WITH pages'() {
        when:
            to Mainpage

        then:
            LoginWithFormUsername.value() == "root"

    }


}
```

These tests are apparently work, i.e. they pass or fail depending on page data.

The problem is that it opens TWO instances of Chrome browser to operate (by number of tests).

How to prevent that? May be reuse browser? Or may be close it after each test?

**UPDATE**

If I add something like below

```
def cleanupSpec() {
    browser.driver.quit()
}
```

then all my tests startin to run twice, moreover, each second run they try with `HtmlUnit` (i.e. with "in memory" web browser, not Chrome).

Comment: i'd assume, that you can not change the driver in `setup`.  your call there to the browser starts the driver, which is configured in your project.  next you change the driver thus a new instance is started and you get the htmlunit (default) and your chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't instantiate the driver yourself when using `GebSpec` because it already handles the lifecycle of a driver instance through a browser instance it lazy initializes in it's [`getBrowser()` method](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/fa05c94f114ffdff4c74f6348ff6e7c11cbd3d95/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebSpec.groovy#L41).

See the sections of The Book of Geb about [how Geb interacts with `WebDriver` instances](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#driver) and about [configuring the driver to be used](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#driver-implementation-configuration) via [the config script](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#the-config-script) to learn more.